# Grand Total Block is not getting displayed in the order emails

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

I am using magento community version 1.9.2.1 the issue I am facing is that the Grand total block in the order confirmation email is not being displayed. Can anyone please help me out.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Copy to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Then add the new variables below line 1346:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
'order' => $this,
'billing' => $this->getBillingAddress(),
'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
// Adds Subtotal to email (don't forget to add the comma above this line)
 'subtotal' => number_format($this->getSubtotal(), 2),
 // Adds Discount to email 
 'discount' => number_format($this->getDiscountAmount(), 2),
 // Adds Grand Total to email (don't forget to remove the comma at the end of this line)
 'total' => number_format($this->getGrandTotal(), 2)
)
);
```

The additional lines will format to two decimal places.

Add the variables to your Transactional Email template:

```
${{var subtotal}}
${{var discount}}
${{var total}}
```